# MomentJS only Spanish will translate 'Invalid date' to local

Tags: momentjs

Below is simple code of moment.js

```
const moment = require('moment')
moment.locale('es') // 'it', 'fr', 'zh', 'ja'..
const myDate = moment.utc('').format('MM/DD/YYYY')
console.log(myDate)
```

Only moment.locale set 'es' it will return 'Fecha invalid' apparently it's Spanish.
But no matter what language I set, like 'it' 'fr' 'zh', it will return 'Invalid date' which is English.
So my question is: why moments handle Spanish differently?

Answer (score 1):

Invalid date originally was a way to handle errors, not locale related, but it changed [here](https://github.com/moment/moment/pull/1140)

I would guess that's why is not updated with all the locales, so the only option before having updated locales is doing it manually:

```js
moment.locale('it'); // 'it', 'fr', 'zh', 'ja'..
moment.updateLocale("it", {
  invalidDate: "data non valida"
});
const myDate = moment.utc('').format('MM/DD/YYYY');

$('#it').text(myDate)
```

```html
Italian Translation: <span id="it"></span>



<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Your guess it's correct, looking at [es](https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/2.29.1/locale/es.js) localization you'll see [`invalidDate: 'Fecha inválida'`](https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/2.29.1/locale/es.js#L112), while there is no `invalidDate` key in the [italian](https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/2.29.1/locale/it.js) localization.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to format the locale - eg. see here: `moment().format('L');    // 07/28/2021` the locale formatting is separate to the normal date formatting as per https://momentjs.com